# VB6 multidimensional array weird statement

Tags: vb6

While reviewing a very old VB6 working code I get a very strange statement.

```
aryValue = aryPersons(8, i)
```

Where `aryValue` and `aryPersons` are multidimensional array and declared as

```
dim aryPersons, aryValue
```

Anyone having any idea what is does? 
I tried the same in test application but it is giving `Type mismatch (Error 13)`

**ANSWER:**
It is my bad to understand the VB code as I was expecting it will be strongly data type language. Actually at `aryPersons(8, i)` a two dimension array were getting stored and while fetching it gives use a 2D array data that can be easily assigned to `aryValue` as it is also a 2D array.
It is strange to me that in 2D array at any position you store a any kind of data even another 2D data.

Comment: If `aryStepPersonOptions` is a multidimensional array, this accesses the element in that array at `(8, i)`, where `i` is presumably an integer variable containing an array index. But we would really need to see more context to be sure.

Comment: @CodyGray what more context you need I will try to provide you.

Comment: Could you post the code in which aryPersons is assigned a value or in which it is redimmed?

Answer (score 4):

It seems likely that `aryStepPersonOptions` has an array as its value:

```
Dim SomeArray(8, 8) As String
Dim aryStepPersonOptions, aryValue
Dim i As Long

SomeArray(8, 8) = "Hello"
aryStepPersonOptions = SomeArray
i = 8
aryValue = aryStepPersonOptions(8, i)
MsgBox aryValue
```

Of course the pseudo-hungarian `ary` prefix used seems to do more to add confusion than otherwise.  Sadly far too much code contains cargo-culted messes like this.  Lets hope nobody copy/pastes my throwaway example `SomeArray` too.

Comment: Yes, `aryStepPersonOptions ` has its value from other function. Till here it is correct and I assumed after `aryValue = aryStepPersonOptions(8, i)` the `aryValue` may become like string but I trembled  to see 'UBound(sryValue)' just after. 
`

Comment: Can you try `UBound(aryValue)` after `aryValue = aryStepPersonOptions(8, i)` this